# XAMPP Access Denied

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

A long date working Xampp (Mysql + Apache) now show message "ACCESS DENIED" on all databases.
This only occurs on a computer with windows 10, another with windows 7 works well.
The access denied occurs on php connection and also in SQLConnect component of embarcadero.
Someone has any idea? Thanks.

```
 CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ictiobase
 GRANT ALL ON ictiobase.* TO 'ictiobasemain'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mainICTIO';
```

And the PHP connection:

```
    $cnx = @mysqli_connect("","ictiobasemain","mainICTIO","ictiobase");
    if (!$cnx) {
        die ("ERRO: NÃO FOI POSSÍVEL CONECTAR AO SERVIDOR!!"); 
        return NULL;
    }
```

Comment: To little information and a to large window of what might be wrong here.. i advice you to make your question more accurate with apache and embarcadero config and code..

Comment: There is a lot of configuration,  but the problem is that its STOPS working from nothing and the very same configurations STILL works on another computer with a backup of these files.

Comment: my guess: db deets are wrong - you able to log into mysql via cmd line with these deets?

Comment: E:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql -uictiobasemain -pmainICTIO -hlocalhost ictiobase
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ictiobasemain'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: never put password in the actual CMD just use `mysql -uusername -p` and login that way

Comment: I can't tell where your permission problem is; within the file system? Within the database? Within something else in XAMPP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obvious solution: reinstalling xampp solved.

Comment: Please explain, and note which permission problem was fixed (file system? database?).